# How to Retrieve key from apple sign in JWK?

Tags: ios, macos, jwt, apple-sign-in, jwk

Apple's public key is located at https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys. It looks like this :

```
{
  "keys": [
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "kid": "AIDOPK1",
      "use": "sig",
      "alg": "RS256",
      "n": "lxrwmuYSAsTfn-lUu4goZSXBD9ackM9OJuwUVQHmbZo6GW4Fu_auUdN5zI7Y1dEDfgt7m7QXWbHuMD01HLnD4eRtY-RNwCWdjNfEaY_esUPY3OVMrNDI15Ns13xspWS3q-13kdGv9jHI28P87RvMpjz_JCpQ5IM44oSyRnYtVJO-320SB8E2Bw92pmrenbp67KRUzTEVfGU4-obP5RZ09OxvCr1io4KJvEOjDJuuoClF66AT72WymtoMdwzUmhINjR0XSqK6H0MdWsjw7ysyd_JhmqX5CAaT9Pgi0J8lU_pcl215oANqjy7Ob-VMhug9eGyxAWVfu_1u6QJKePlE-w",
      "e": "AQAB"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is an RSA public key with modulo and exponent. How to compute the rsa.PublicKey from m and e ?